# New to Bootstrap - How to intepret grid sizing

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm pretty new to Bootstrap and am trying to understand the grid system. If I have something like this:

```
.col-md-6 .col-xs-12
```

I know that for a medium size it'll consume 6 units and for extra small size it will consume all 12. However, what will it use for lg and sm?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will use 6 for 'lg', and 12 for 'sm'..

You only need to write classes for the smaller of the breakpoints you want to support. So what you have is shorthand for..

```
.col-lg-6 .col-md-6 .col-sm-12 .col-xs-12
```

Demo: http://www.bootply.com/124738